# Can I limit the file size for a attachinary/cloudinary upload

Tags: image-uploading, cloudinary

Using attachinary, in combination with cloudinary on Rails - is there a way to limit the size (width & height) of the uploaded image file before uploading it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an incoming transformation to limit the dimensions of the uploaded image. Larger images will be scaled down, e.g.

```
<%= form.attachinary_file_field :image, cloudinary: { transformation: { width: 200, height: 200, crop: :limit } } %>
```

Comment: I modified my code to look as you suggest

= f.input :image, as: :attachinary, cloudinary: { :transformation => {:width=>125, :height=>150, :crop=>:limit } }

but when I go and look on the cloudinary site, the submitted image is still the full size... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like attachinary simple_form integration doesn't support these parameters. You will need to either use a standard form or open an issue with attachinary.